# How to create a dynamic form vuejs vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

i'm trying to make a dynamic form to work.
I have an array of competences, and inside, i have a skills array. Each skill of the entire competence is going to be evaluated, so it need to have an answer.

Everything is organized in a v-stepper with dynamic steps, and my form fields are being generated by a v-for. For each skill the answer need to have, maybe an array like

```
answers: [
  skillId:
  skillLevel:
  feedback:
  feedforward:
  ...
]
```

My question is, being the form dynamically generated, how can i set the v-models for each field? Because a competence can have many skills, so the models need to be different to bind.

Here's my code

```
<template>
  <v-stepper v-model="e1" :appraisal="appraisal">
    <v-stepper-header>
      <template v-for="n in steps">
        <v-stepper-step :key="`${n}-step`" :step="n" :complete="e1 > n" editable></v-stepper-step>
        <v-divider v-if="n !== steps" :key="n"></v-divider>
      </template>
    </v-stepper-header>
    <v-stepper-items>
      <v-stepper-content v-for="n in steps" :key="`${n}-content`" :step="n">
        <v-row align="center" justify="center">
          <v-col cols="4">
            <v-subheader class="headline">{{appraisal.appraisalCompetences[n-1].competence.name}}</v-subheader>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-row justify="center">
              <v-col cols="3">
                <v-subheader class="title">Fatores</v-subheader>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="2">
                <v-subheader class="title">Presença da competência</v-subheader>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="2">
                <v-subheader class="title">Feedback do Gestor</v-subheader>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="2">
                <v-subheader class="title">Auto Avaliação</v-subheader>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="3">
                <v-subheader class="title">Feedforward</v-subheader>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <template v-for="competence in appraisal.appraisalCompetences[n-1]">
          <v-form :key="`${competence.competenceId}-form`">
            <v-row v-for="(item, index) in competence.competenceSkills" :key="index">
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-row class="mb-n10" justify="center">
                  <v-col cols="3" class="mt-4">
                    <span>{{item.skill.name}}</span>
                  </v-col>

                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-select
                      v-model="answers.skillLevel"
                      outlined
                      :items="selectLevels"
                      :name="`skill-level-${item.skill.skillId}`"
                      label="Selecione"
                      item-text="level"
                      item-value="value"
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-textarea outlined rows="3" :name="`skill-feedback-${item.skill.skillId}`"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-textarea
                      outlined
                      rows="3"
                      :name="`skill-selfappraisal-${item.skill.skillId}`"
                    ></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-textarea outlined rows="3" :name="`skill-feedforward-${item.skill.skillId}`"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-form>
        </template>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-row align="center" justify="space-between">
              <v-btn tile large color="error" @click="previous(n)">
                <v-icon dark left>mdi-arrow-left</v-icon>Voltar
              </v-btn>

              <v-btn tile large color="success" @click="next(n)">
                Continuar
                <v-icon dark right>mdi-arrow-right</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-row>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-stepper-content>
    </v-stepper-items>
  </v-stepper>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    e1: 1,
    steps: 1,
    appraisal: [],
    selectLevels: [
      { value: 0, level: "Ausente" },
      { value: 1, level: "A Desenvolver" },
      { value: 2, level: "Satifatória" },
      { value: 3, level: "Excelencia" },
      { value: 4, level: "Não se aplica" }
    ],
    answers: [
      {
        competenceId: "",
        appraisalId: "",
        skillId: "",
        skillLevel: "",
        feedback: "",
        selfAppraisal: "",
        feedforward: ""
      }
    ]
  }),
  created() {
    this.initialize();
  },
  methods: {
    initialize() {
      axios
        .get(`/questionnaire/appraisals/${this.$route.params.appraisalId}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.appraisal = response.data;
          this.steps = this.appraisal.appraisalCompetences.length;
        });
    },
    previous(n) {
      if (this.e1 == 1) {
        this.$router.push("/app/pdc");
      } else {
        this.e1 = n - 1;
      }
    },
    next(n) {
      if (n === this.steps) {
        this.e1 = 1;
      } else {
        this.e1 = n + 1;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**EDITED**

Let me try to improve the question

In my form, for each competence, i have a set of skills that will be evaluated. So for each of these skills, i need to have a separate answer, like
for skill 1

```
  skillId:
  skillLevel:
  feedback:
  feedforward:
  ...
```

And so on for all other skills. after the user types the answers for every skill in the competence, i need to do the same for competence 2 an so on.
The problema is in the answers part of the form, I don't know how to make every single line count as one answer and after add them to an array of answers

This is what i came up so far

```js
<template v-for="competence in appraisal.appraisalCompetences[n-1]">
          <v-row v-for="(item, index) in competence.competenceSkills" :key="index">
            <v-col cols="12">
              <v-form :key="`${item.skillId}-form`">
                <v-row class="mb-n10" justify="center">
                  <v-col cols="3" class="mt-4">
                    <span>{{item.skill.name}}</span>
                  </v-col>

                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-select
                      v-model="`${item.skillId}-form`.skillLevel"
                      outlined
                      :items="selectLevels"
                      label="Selecione"
                      item-text="level"
                      item-value="value"
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-textarea v-model="answer.feedback" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-textarea v-model="answer.selfAppraisal" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-textarea v-model="answer.feedForward" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-form>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </template>
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    e1: 1,
    steps: 1,
    appraisal: [],
    selectLevels: [
      { value: 0, level: "Ausente" },
      { value: 1, level: "A Desenvolver" },
      { value: 2, level: "Satifatória" },
      { value: 3, level: "Excelencia" },
      { value: 4, level: "Não se aplica" }
    ],
    answer: {
      competenceId: "",
      skillId: "",
      skillLevel: "",
      feedback: "",
      selfAppraisal: "",
      feedForward: ""
    },
    anwers: []
  }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all there are some good vuejs-vuetify ready form generator, which isbased on standard json-schema.

see below examples and projects, specially the github code for more detail and idea about how to create a good form generator,so you can use them.

https://github.com/koumoul-dev/vuetify-jsonschema-form

https://koumoul-dev.github.io/vuetify-jsonschema-form/latest/?example=basic

if you want to write some project from scrach, you shoud consider that the idea is simple like rendering a inline edit in a table (by using refrence by means of object passing):
see below example:
[image]

watch the logic, you should index properly, when i debugged your code, the code always refrences to answer 0 to 5 at least. so you couldnt make it work. 
read below with care to fix you problem:

```
  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-select
                      v-model="answers[index + (competence.competenceId-1)*competence.competenceSkills.length ].skillLevel"
                      outlined
                      :items="selectLevels"
                      label="Selecione"
                      item-text="level"
                      item-value="value"
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-textarea v-model="answers[index + (competence.competenceId-1)*competence.competenceSkills.length].feedBack" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-textarea v-model="answers[index + (competence.competenceId-1)*competence.competenceSkills.length].selfAppraisal" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-textarea v-model="answers[index + (competence.competenceId-1)*competence.competenceSkills.length].feedForward" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
                  </v-col>
```

or you can use a better idea, seperation of answers like below:

see below for how i fixed the problem to get the idea:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. About the form generators, actually I don't have much time to learn how to work with them, so I preffer to build from scratch. I know that i can use the v-models that way, but my form is rather complex than this. I'm trying to use computed properties to add answers to an array right now.. Without much success

Comment: ok, can you provide a reproduction in github, to better examine the project and try to help you better?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Actually I can't use Github because of legal restrictions of the company. But i'll try to reproduce on my personal computer when i have some time

Comment: Hello @SeyyedKhandon, I've uploaded a version in my personal GitHub, check it out https://github.com/felipe-kosouski/form-stepper, I'm still stuck in this. Now the problem is that I can fill every field in one step, but when I change the step for other fields (that actually are the same, but for other object), it keeps track of the first ones that I filled one step back. I can't figure out how to proceed with this.

Comment: i added the two solution for your problem.  so check it.

Comment: Thanks @Seyyed, the second option, making the answers separated by competence is a better option both by code legibility and organization. Thank you for you time and help

Comment: You're welcome, if this answer helped you and solved your problem, then choose it as the right answer and an upvote, to other people if faced the same problem, they have a clear view to follow the answer